# FCM GEM HTTP v1 how to get access token?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM gem to send push notification. The Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) works. But I want use Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1). FCM gem manual shows:

```
fcm = FCM.new(
    API_TOKEN,
   '/path/to/credentials.json',
   FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
)
```

I have credentials.json, project_id, but I am not able to find how to create and manage API_TOKEN. Can I use FCM gem for it or should I use another one?

Answer (score 0):

API_TOKEN seems to be the same SERVER_KEY that you use with Legacy API.

FCM then uses the SERVER_KEY to fetch the short-lived ACCESS_TOKEN.

fcm.rb code -> https://github.com/decision-labs/fcm/blob/40eb6efa191e5d092ad40fe81da81a4c1cbf39fe/lib/fcm.rb#L319C8-L319C8